# error with adding existing *.mdf file as an existing item

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I have an existing database(myDatabse) that I created with Microsoft Sql Managenent studio and want to add the myDatabse.mdf file as an existing item(with Visual web Developer express edition)

but get the error message "the file cannot be opened because it is using another process. ..."

In my view it is not open or being used and adding a .mdb file didn't give any problems.

Is there another why one should(can) add the database to the App_data folder so that one can establish a connection to the database.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the running sql server service(s) do not allow to copy database files. To copy `.mdf` file, detach the database:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Expand Databases
3. Right-click on your database > point to *Tasks* > select *Detach* > click *OK*
4. Manually add the file to `App_Folder`
5. After copying, go to Management Studio right-click on *Databases*  > Attach > specify database > click *Add*